How to cache GraphQL response in Apollo Client?
I have a React app where I am using Apollo client to handle GraphQL queries and caching.
I have two GraphQL queries, one that fetches a whole menu and another that fetches top level menu sections.
I fetch the whole menu when I first load the app in an attempt to cache the menu data. I then call the query that fetches the menu top level sections which I would expect to fetch from the cache but for some reason the data is not available from the cache and must fetch from the network.
The first query that fetches the whole menu looks like this
query GetMenu(
  $menuId: ID
  $restaurantId: ID!
  $filter: MenuSectionFilterInput
) {
  getMenu(menuId: $menuId, restaurantId: $restaurantId) {
    id
    sections(filter: $filter) {
      ...Section
      sections {
        ...Section
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment Section on MenuSection {
  id
  items(restaurantId: $restaurantId) {
    ...Item
  }
}

The second query that fetches all the top level sections looks like this
query GetMenuSections($restaurantId: ID!, $getMenuFilter: MenuFilterInput) {
  getMenu(restaurantId: $restaurantId, filter: $getMenuFilter) {
    id
    sections {
      name
      id
    }
  }
}

Since the second query is run at a later stage than the first one, should the sections already be in the cache?
I am trying to run the following query with fetchPolicy: 'cache-only', which fails because the data isn't in the cache. It passes if I allow it to fetch from network.
useQuery(GET_MENU_SECTIONS,
  {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-only',
    variables: {
      restaurantId,
      getMenuFilter
    }
  }
);

Do the query args make a difference to how things get cached? Do both GetMenu and GetMenuSections need to have the same args in order for it to cache?
I don't have any typePolicies set up in my Apollo Client that would override default caching policies. I did try to add a custom policy for getMenu but it didn't work and shouldn't even be necessary since both queries are querying for id fields which is what should get used for caching.
How do I make the GetMenuSections query use the already cached data?

Yes, arguements on fields need to match to be able to fetch it from cache. You can override the keyArgs in your typePolicies for it to cache successfully.

It would appear that your first query doesn't fetch the name of each Section, so it won't be available in cache for the second query

Have you tried ‘readQuery’?  Looks like it should meet your needs.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readquery
“If your cache contains data for all of the query's fields, readQuery returns an object that matches the shape of the query.”
If that doesn’t work, probably good to check out the shape of your cache using the Apollo Dec Tools chrome extension.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
